# Decode HTML entities with Angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to decode html entities from a string using and Angular JS filter.

I have a view that looks like the following:

```
<div class="roboto medium-gray">
   <span class="item-description">{{item.description | plaintext}}</span>
</div>
```

As of right now I am applying a filter that strips tags:

```
.filter('plaintext', function() {
  return function(text) {
    return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
  };
})
```

I am trying to determine a way where i can decode any html enties that are in there.

`item.description` is `"A large house with wrap around porch & pool"`

right now after `item.description` gets passed through the `plaintext` filter it comes out as:

`A large house with wrap around porch &amp; pool`

I want it to replace the `&amp;` with `&`

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-bind-html`, like so:

```
<div class="roboto medium-gray">
   <span class="item-description" ng-bind-html="item.description | plaintext"></span>
</div>
```

For more information see [official API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks as though this isn't working with the plaintext filter. When I do it that way I get nothing in the UI, get the following: ```Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.```

Comment: had to add ```$sce``` into the filter